# How do I reuse my layout with handlebars in express?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Okay I don't want to include my actual layout in every view.

So my views would look something like

#### layout.hbs

```
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    {{ content }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### index.hbs

```
<div>my index content</div>
```

#### help.hbs

```
<div>my help content</div>
```

---

When I use my express routes like the following examples I just had to include my whole layout stuff in each view - which is obviously a bad idea.

#### express routes

```
app.use('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {content: 'foo'});
});
app.use('/about', function (req, res) {
    res.render('about', {content: 'foo'});
});
```

So the question is: How do I reuse my layout in handlebar views?

My idea was to compile my content additionaly like

```
app.use('/', function (req:express.Request, res:express.Response, next:Function) {
    fs.readFile(path.join(viewPath, 'index.hbs'), function(err, text){
        var template = hbs.handlebars.compile(text);
        var content = template({foo: 1234});
        res.render('layout', {content: content}); 
    }); 
});
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `express-handlebars` and give it a default layout.

```
var hbs = exphbs.create({
    extname:'hbs',
    layoutsDir:  '/path/to/layouts',
    defaultLayout: 'main'
});

// Initialize engine
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);

// Set engine
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Once the layout is set, you can just call `res.render({content: content});`